# Can I query/change the polling rate on USB keyboard in OSX?

Tags: keyboard, usb

Is it possible to check the polling rate of my keyboard in OSX? Is it possible to change it? I'm using a standard Apple USB keyboard.

Comment: What is the point of changing the polling rate?

Comment: @Keyboard_Gamer I want to log key press times with the greatest accuracy possible. It's not for gaming purposes.

Comment: For what it’s worth, USB Overdrive allows this, but **not** with Apple input devices. Given how popular and prevalent that utility is, I doubt there’s another solution for an Apple keyboard.

Comment: @Phong I don't see any options for this in the application. Are you USB overdrive can modify the polling rate? I've seen at least one person [claim otherwise](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/dgbw7/is_there_any_way_to_utilize_a_higher_polling_rate/): *"USB Overdrive doesn't affect the sampling rate unfortunately, only the acceleration curve which has many fixes"*

Comment: I actually don’t use USB Overdrive, but I’d read that somewhere. If it can’t do that, my mistake.